# Catch browser Network log payload data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, logging, browser, google-chrome-devtools

im using below Java code with JS execution to fetch Network tab log from browser inspector for future use but I cant find detailed Payload of some particular API response.

```
public static String getNetworkLog() throws Throwable {
        WebDriver driver = DriverManager.getInstance().getDriver();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        String scriptToExecute = "var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;";
        String netData = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptToExecute).toString();
        return netData;
    }
```

How can I find a Payload data?